# How do I make a RegExp from a "literal notation" string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make an input where users can write a custom regex in *literal notation*.  I then want to create a RegExp out of that literal notation string.

Something like this:

```
const literalNotationStr = `/literal/i`;
const regex = makeRegexFromLiteralNotationString(literalNotationStr)

function makeRegexFromLiteralNotationString(str: string): RegExp {
  // ... magic code ...
}
```

Is there a [function I'm missing here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or is this the kind of thing where you have to parse and build yourself?

Comment: Since it's from an input, do they really need to provide the `/` delimiters? Other sites that do this put the delimiters outside the input to show that they're not needed. The flags could go in a separate input.

Comment: ...or the way [regex101](https://regex101.com/) does it is pretty nice.

Comment: You say `literal notation` string but what does that mean ? If you have an input box, everything that is _typed_ in that box goes into a variable unchanged. That variable is passed to the RegExp function unchanged. I guess I don't understand.

Comment: @Maxt8r: They mean the content of the string contains regex literal notation.

Comment: If on the otherhand, you are trying to parse delimiters for some reason, you make the same mistake as regex101.com does, it's an added user burdon that should not be .

Comment: @slappy can you give an example of regex literal notation ? Cause I don't know that.

Comment: `/foo/gi`. The literal is delimited by the forward slashes, with the trailing flags optional.

Comment: @slappy but as I said, those are delimiters that have nothing to do with regex syntax.

Comment: If you are trying to discern the _flag options_ use another input box, otherwise the problem of delimiters will take you down..

Comment: @Maxt8r: They have to do with the literal syntax, but not the regex grammar.

Comment: @slappy as I said literal syntax is not related to regex. It's too complex to discern delimiters within a regex context, stay away from that, trust me.

Comment: @Maxt8r: Literal syntax in a language exists to create instances of certain types without the aid of things like constructors. JavaScript includes regular expression literals, which are delimited by the forward slashes.

Comment: Then use a JS parser, don't do it yourself. Is it that simple you could do it ? Where do delimiters start and end when quote like operators and regex ?

Comment: @Maxt8r: They could parse away just the literal delimiters very easily, and then use the `RegExp` constructor. Using `const re = new Function("return " + literalNotationStr)()` would use the built-in JS parser, but I'd think that it *may* be more computationally expensive, but I'm not sure.

Comment: ...and there's no guarantee that the user would have limited their input to regex syntax.

Comment: I claim that regex syntax conceals delimiters like no other language. Do what you think, but I think JS `/../` notation itself uses very rudimentary rules to avoid regex constructs. Might as well find the firs and last `/` and hope for the best.

Comment: @Maxt8r: That's the point. Those are the regex literal delimiters. Just need to account for the optional flags at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to

(1) grab the flags

(2) slice off the slash delimiters from the beginning and end of the pattern

```js
const literalNotationStr = `/literal/i`;
const regex = makeRegexFromLiteralNotationString(literalNotationStr)
console.log(regex.test('LITERAL'));

function makeRegexFromLiteralNotationString(str){
  const [, patternContent, flags] = str.match(/^\/(.+)\/(\w*)$/);
  return new RegExp(patternContent, flags);
}
```

But you'll have to make sure the input string has its backslashes properly escaped, eg:

```
const literalNotationStr = String.raw`/foo\w+/i`;
```

and not

```
const literalNotationStr = `/foo\w+/i`;
```

Answer (score -1):

The flag has to be provided as the second argument. You can e.g. split the literal to get the `Regex` body and the flag separately and then use it within the `Regex` constructor.

```js
const literalNotationStr = '/literal/i';

const createRegex = (str) => {
   const [, literal, flag] = str.split('/');
   return new RegExp(literal, flag);
};

console.log(createRegex(literalNotationStr));
```

Comment: You can't reliably use `split` for this, since the character you're splitting on can be used within the regex itself.